# Would a question on what is small ball be to broad

Tags: discussion

Exactly the title.  Would a question on what is small ball be too broad?

Without being too artificial I am trying to ask questions that might be of value to the community.

Comment: Maybe create a tag instead with some explanations and links ?

Comment: @RaduMurzea Not sure it make a difference but I meant small ball.   I tried asking the question and answering but it quickly seem to be broad.   There was a question a while ago where a guy asked about learning to play small ball and I was clear he did not even understand the strategy of small ball.

Answer (score 1):

Personally (and I recognise I'm a relatively new contributor here, so don't have the full experience of how this site has developed before and since it went into beta), I would say that this is not too broad a question.

There is literature to refer to which defines the concept of small ball, you can cite specific examples of it and define the term quite closely IMO. I also think - as you point out - that it is likely to be a useful question for the community and it seems like if this site is ever to graduate from beta it needs more questions!